# Cause of event id 1309 asp.net 4.0 unhandled exception in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I am working on website, yesterday i faced a problem i.e server got down. i have checked the event log files then i came to know that it was due to "event id 1309 asp.net 4.0 unhandled exception" error. i just restore the back up of the website and restart the website it got worked.

Now my concern is why i got this error: is the criteria i had followed is actual way to recover from this error. i am asking this because might be we will not have latest code back up in future then what will we do? so i am asking to experts

1. why this errors occurred, what is exact caused for this.?
2. Best way to overcome this.

I have read the[This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941386) and came to know this is due to
**This problem occurs because the public headers properties of the Request.Headers property and of the Response.Headers property become non-serializable after you install the MS07-040 security update**

But i have not used "Request.Headers".. please guide me.

Comment: Did you really have to restore a backup just because of an unhandled exception? Did you try just restarting website? Can you provide more details of the error?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev let me very clear to you: actually the team handling the server had told me the same that he had to restore the code and restart the IIS.. and sent me the error code with message i.e.

event id 1309 asp.net 4.0 unhandled exception 
When i have checked on net it is telling some other story for this error, so i am asking this question: why it occurred and how to resolve this